# Windows phone 7 home screen unpin/re-arrange icons effect?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was looking for a way to implement the unpin/re-arrange effect in my windows phone 7 application, just like the effect on the phone's home screen (holding an icon enables the user to unpin it or move it around, while the other icons re-arrange themselves accordingly).

I have searched around this site and googled around, but I can't find anything. Does anyone know how to implement this effect, or if I can get the code from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following links:

http://www.ginktage.com/2011/01/backgroundimage-and-pin-to-start-in-windows-phone-7-using-visual-studio/

http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=177

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Vivek. But I'm trying to implement the pin/unpin functionality so that I can pin icons inside a listBox in my app, not pin/unpin icons on the home screen itself.

Comment: Where exactly you want to pin the list box items to?

Comment: A listbox, so every item in the listbox is draggable and pinnable.

Comment: Hmm, so there's no built-in function..I thought there would be since the phone uses it. I'll take your advice and build it myself then, thanks!